# my icon background is transparent how can I make the check circle white?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to display the verification icon but the problem is the check icon in the middle is transparent how can I make it white ?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import MaterialCommunityIcons from '@expo/vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const VerificationCheck = () => {
  return (
    <MaterialCommunityIcons style={s.verificationIcon} name="check-decagram" size={16} color="deepskyblue" />
  )
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  verificationIcon: {
    marginLeft: 2
  },
})

export default VerificationCheck
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. Absolutely position the icon on top of a white circle
2. Find the icon's SVG and set the check shape to have a white fill
3. Get a designer to make you a version of the icon with the coloring you want